# netbeans error "git authentication not supported"

Tags: java, git, github, netbeans

I work the java project over netbeans. I want to upload github repository this java project. I maked initialize repository  in team tab over netbeans. I maked project commit with over netbeans. Netbeans gave error message that ı pushed project. I cant upload project to my github repository. I tried github username and github password also github username and github pat to over netbeans. Although I did these, netbeans gave errors message "javasnakegame.git: authentication not supported".

Comment: Guessing you're using your password instead of a PAT

Comment: Im so sorry ı dont know PAT. What is PAT?

Comment: I maked pat and ı entered with pat but same errror

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.